# Running jupyter-dash in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, jupyter-lab

I have created a docker file, by following `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkOKkrKqI-k`
The docker builds perfectly fine and runs jupyter lab. Also, I can run a simple dash application.

```
import plotly.express as px
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
# Load Data
df = px.data.tips()
# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("JupyterDash Demo"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    html.Label([
        "colorscale",
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='colorscale-dropdown', clearable=False,
            value='plasma', options=[
                {'label': c, 'value': c}
                for c in px.colors.named_colorscales()
            ])
    ]),
])
# Define callback to update graph
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input("colorscale-dropdown", "value")]
)
def update_figure(colorscale):
    return px.scatter(
        df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color="size",
        color_continuous_scale=colorscale,
        render_mode="webgl", title="Tips"
    )
# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode='inline') --> This doesn't work
app.run_server(mode='jupyterlab') --> This doesn't work
# app.run_server(mode='external') --> This doesn't work
```

In dockerfile I expose port 8888 and 8050. Also after the build of the docker file, I run the the docker file with expose port commands to 8888 and 8050 respectively like below.

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8050:8050 <image-name>`

However, when I run my dash application on an `external mode`:
Then it shows me [image: app running]
and when I try to connect that URL, I found it's not working.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I know how to use the flask to open up the application, but I would like to follow the traditional way as suggested in the video.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.0

RUN git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it.git ~/.bash_it && \
    bash ~/.bash_it/install.sh --silent

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --upgrade \
    numpy \
    pandas \
    dash \
    Jupyterlab \
    ipywidgets \
    jupyterlab-git \
    jupyter-dash 

RUN jupyter lab build
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
#     pip install --upgrade \
#     jupyterlab "pywidgets>=7.5" 
RUN jupyter labextension install \
    jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3 \
    @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager \
    @jupyterlab/git

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
COPY config/ /root/.jupyter/

EXPOSE 8888 8050
VOLUME /notebooks
WORKDIR /notebooks
# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD jupyter lab --ip=* --port=8888 --allow-root
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile too please?

Comment: @JakeNelson yes, I have added the docker file in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my answer is the right approach, but I made it work.
if anyone has any better solutions please post here.

- the docker file remains the same.
- after the build of the docker image I run,

`docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 8050:8050 <ImageName>`

The only change I made is (the hostname in `app.run_server`)
So my main command looks like this :

`app.run_server(mode='inline', host="0.0.0.0", port=8050, dev_tools_ui=True)` 
this works for both `inline`, `external`, and `jupyterlab`.